# Discarding deep link if it contains specific path

Tags: android, deep-linking

I have an implementation of deeplink in my manifest which is working fine

```
    <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
          <data
              android:host="blablabla.com"
              android:scheme="https" />
          <data
              android:host="${applicationId}"
              android:scheme="bla" />
</intent-filter>
```

I am wondering is there any way to NOT ACCEPT a deep link URL if it contains a specific path? E.g. Do not accept (don't open the app) if `blablabla.com/specificPath` but do accept any other paths with the same hostname.

Comment: Android deep linking does not provide a way to explicitly exclude some URLs

Comment: I see. Would it work if, for that specific path, we use a different URL, and redirect to the same URL from the server side?
e.g. notblabla.com/specificPath that redirects to blabla.com/specificPath when opened in web browser

Comment: its not possible but you can open your app on a spewcfic url like just open your app  blablabla.com/your/path so its avoide to open on other url

Comment: No, it would not work that way either. The intent-filter will resolve the last redirected URL

Comment: Thanks, guys for your help!

Answer (score 4):

Android [Deep Links](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking) **does not provide a way to explicitly exclude URLs, the best practice is define specifically the urls that you want to access** to your app using deep Links.

In this case to access URLs like :

```
www.blablabla.com/specificPath
www.blablabla.com/specificPath/
www.blablabla.com/specificPath/default.aspx
www.blablabla.com/specificPath/other/
```

You will define the configuration of your intent filter using `android:pathPrefix` as:

```
 <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
          <data
              android:host="blablabla.com"
              android:scheme="https" 
              android:pathPrefix="/specificPath" />
</intent-filter>
```